# I'm getting an error on a POST method that uses TeamTailor's API

Tags: java, api, post, unirest

I'm trying to implement two methods: one that creates a candidate that is going to be inserted into teamtailor, the other one takes the candidate and puts it into a job offer.

Apparently, as i'm debugging the method, it looks like it throws an exception when generating the response. If i try to print the body of the request, it gives me a json containing the error. If I try to send the request with postman, it returns a 201. So it creates the candidate effectively.

Problem is, even if the exception is thrown, the candidate still gets created.

Additional problem: I can't call the other method to create the job application (i.e. put the candidate on the job) if the "createcandidate" one throws an exception.

This is the createCandidateUniRest method:

```
private String createCandidateUniRest(String nome, String cognome, String email) throws UnirestException {
        Unirest.setTimeouts(0, 0);
        HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("https://api.teamtailor.com/v1/candidates")
                .header("Authorization", "Token token=" + authToken)
                .header("X-Api-Version", "20210218")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json")
                .body("{\n    " +
                        "\"data\": {\n        " +
                        "\"type\": \"candidates\",\n        " +
                        "\"attributes\": {\n            " +
                        "\"first-name\": \"" + nome + "\",\n            " +
                        "\"last-name\": \"" + cognome + "\",\n            " +
                        "\"email\": \"" + email + "\"\n        }\n    }\n}")
                .asString();

        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response.getBody());
        String candidateId = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("data").getString("id");

        return candidateId;
    }
```

This is the other method that's supposed to put the person into the job offer:

```
public Response createJobApplication(String nome, String cognome, String email) throws CandidateCreationException {

        String candidateId = "";

        try {
            candidateId = createCandidateUniRest(nome, cognome, email);
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/vnd.api+json");
        JsonObject data = new JsonObject();
        JsonObject attributes = new JsonObject();
        attributes.addProperty("cover-letter", "");
        attributes.addProperty("sourced", true);
        attributes.addProperty("send-user-notifications", true);
        data.add("attributes", attributes);
        JsonObject candidate = new JsonObject();
        candidate.addProperty("type", "candidates");
        candidate.addProperty("id", candidateId);
        JsonObject relationships = new JsonObject();
        relationships.add("candidate", candidate);
        JsonObject job = new JsonObject();
        job.addProperty("type", "jobs");
        job.addProperty("id", jobId);
        relationships.add("job", job);
        data.add("relationships", relationships);
        data.addProperty("type", "job-applications");
        JsonObject jobApplication = new JsonObject();
        jobApplication.add("data", data);
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, jobApplication.toString());
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.teamtailor.com/v1/job-applications")
                .method("POST", body)
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Token token=" + authToken)
                .addHeader("X-Api-Version", "20210218")
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json")
                .build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

I tried with postman, and the requests (i.e. TeamTailor's APIs) seem to work. But my methods don't. I tried to debug too and I'm getting this error: Must use either different key or  iv for GCM encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the JSON had to be properly formatted.